# TypeScript type infer for function with argument

Tags: typescript

I have inteface

```
interface CheckNActSetup<C> {
    context: (event: Event) => C;
    exec: (context: C) => any[];
}
```

and the class method:

```
class Test {
    register<C>(item: CheckNActSetup<C>) {

    }
}
```

then I would like to use the metod as follow:

```
let x = new Test();
x.register({
   context: e => ({ value: "A" }),
   exec: context => context.value
})
```

but here 'context' parameter in 'exec' property is >unknow<. I would like the compiler to infer that context type is: { value: string }

when I add following (e: Event) it works:

```
let x = new Test();
x.register({
   context: (e: Event) => ({ value: "A" }),
   exec: context => context.value

})
```

How to get the proper context variable type without adding (e: Event)?

My final goal is to have interface defintion as follow:

```
interface CheckNActSetup<D, C> {
defs: (event: Event) => D,
context: (defs: D) => C;
exec: (context: C) => any[];
when: ((context: C) => boolean)[]; }
```

Comment: It does not work when you add `(e: Event)` [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=17&ssc=3&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIAsIINYDkCCCYAyhGAK4AOAPKgHzIDeAUMm8ggPbgQAeYALmQAKCADcI4IQFEJ4AJTIAvA1QBuVuz5Yhwrj35DUilcjggAngG0AuhoC+zZggA2cAM7vkAFQjuwTJpsUBAA5sD+0LR0wsCQALZGmDgERKQUNPSKLEHIjo7MLmTIvMrIIBAA7j5+YMLyGrwAdCHhkVDCLOz6kIYiEDJyYCYMnchicC7kA8gARPizefIANEHaCEI9fAGmW-xNE1MQTvbyQA) Please post reproducible example demonstrating the issue. On top of that `"A"` is not of type `any[]` - it is not an Array.

Comment: This is what I was about to get and looks like works:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIAsIINYDkCCCYAyhGAK4AOAPACIA0aAfMgN4BQyXyAJhDAGcAXMgAUEAG4RwIgKJTwASmQBeFrQDcnbggD24CAA8wI0X0EjaytWi3dkRrKb0HjI1NZZwQATwDaALpaAL7s7AgANnACAsgAKhACYGzaXFAQAObASdB0jKhMosCQALbumDgERKQUNAzMyhypyKGh7BFkyIaqyCAQAO7xiWCiilrshgB06Vk5UKIc9ubCDgrJNgvIEnAR+CIARPj7LYr0zS6Qbrz8sRusyBlkAGo7e9eCk9u7J2f2jggiC5GdYsPzIIHGSaPMAvb4BdjBRRAA

But monaco editor show error: claims, that "defs" in "context" is unknown

Comment: you are using TS 4.6.x or earlier, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked that your code works fine under TS 4.7 but does not compile under 4.6 with error message `Object is of type 'unknown'.`

Check TS 4.7 Release Notes: [Improved Function Inference in Objects and Methods](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-7.html#improved-function-inference-in-objects-and-methods)

> TypeScript 4.7 can now perform more granular inferences from functions within objects and arrays. This allows the types of these functions to consistently flow in a left-to-right manner just like for plain arguments.
>
> ```ts
> declare function f<T>(arg: {
>    produce: (n: string) => T,
>    consume: (x: T) => void }
> ): void;
> // Works
> f({
>    produce: () => "hello",
>    consume: x => x.toLowerCase()
> });
> // Works
> f({
>    produce: (n: string) => n,
>    consume: x => x.toLowerCase(),
> });
> // Was an error, now works.
> f({
>    produce: n => n,
>    consume: x => x.toLowerCase(),
> });
> // Was an error, now works.
> f({
>    produce: function () { return "hello"; },
>    consume: x => x.toLowerCase(),
> });
> // Was an error, now works.
> f({
>    produce() { return "hello" },
>    consume: x => x.toLowerCase(),
> });
> ```
>
> Inference failed in some of these examples because knowing the type of their produce functions would indirectly request the type of arg before finding a good type for T. TypeScript now gathers functions that could contribute to the inferred type of T and infers from them lazily.
>
> For more information, you can take a look at the specific modifications to our inference process.